# Does switch iterate every case in java

Tags: java, switch-statement

In a switch with multiple cases and a default, if one of the case conditions is met, will it still see if the rest of the switch cases after are met as well?

In other words, can I use a switch to count errors?

Comment: Provide some example what do you want to achieve with code snippet.

Comment: It depends... Please show use your case(s) here.

Answer (score 2):

Well yes, if you use the `break` keyword, then the switch stops at the current `case`, but if you don't then it will actually iterate over all the remaining cases and execute them.
This is why you should write `break` in to your `switch`.

**Bad switch**

```
int i = 2;
switch (i) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("1");
    case 2:
        System.out.println("2");
    case 3:
        System.out.println("3");
    default:
        System.out.println("default");
}
```

prints: `2 3 default`

**Correct switch**

```
int i = 2;
switch (i) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("1");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("2");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("3");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("default");
}
```

prints: `2`

Comment: There are situations where a `return` may be used instead of a `break`, but that depends on the method rather than the `switch` statement itself.